# Limit of Sum with Binomial coefficients 3

Tags: limits

Compute $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{2r}3^r}{\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{2r+1}3^r}$$

Please help..I found this question on a test and I am not sure about the answer.

Answer (score 4):

if your fraction is $\frac{A_n}{B_n}$ you may observe that:
$$
(1-\sqrt{3})^{2n} = A_n-\sqrt{3}B_n
$$
this gives
$$
\frac{A_n}{B_n}=\sqrt{3} +r_n
$$
where $r_n \to 0$